# How to use cq:includeClientLib in CQ5 to include CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, aem

What are the js and css include concepts in CQ5 using clientLibrary[cq:includeClientLib]? It would be great to have an example with screen shot.

Answer (score 7):

With reference to your question, please find the below link:
http://experiencedelivers.adobe.com/cemblog/en/experiencedelivers/2012/12/clientlibs-explained-by-example.html

Answer (score -1):

Create a node inside /etc/designs  Ex : (Name : myDesign  type must be cq:clientLibraryFolder )
add Node Name : categories , Type : String[] , value =  myDesign

Add the css folder and JS folder and also css.txt and js.txt.

Add this below code snippet to include your all css and js.